# How to fix jsdoc autocomplete not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a project where my jsdoc autocomplete doesn't work in vscode.

Any ideas why or settings I can check to figure out why hitting `enter` doesn't automatically add a line with a `*`?

[image]

These are my enabled extensions:

[image]

Comment: Your jsdoc autocomplete works differently from my built-in version.  For me, one extra line with `*\t` is automatically inserted between the end "tags".  Do you have any conflicting extensions?  I also note that for me, if you put the cursor at the end of the opening tag and then `enter` I do get asterisked lines.

Comment: `For me, one extra line with *\t is automatically inserted between the end "tags".`

That's what i'm expecting too.

Comment: I would just disable all extensions ans see if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on my Angular project. What I did is to add `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"` per language like this:

```js
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
  }
```

This works for me but it's annoying though because you have to do it per language. But I think they're working on this. [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51935)

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue, I got it fixed by setting the `showWords` to `true`

```
"editor.suggest.showWords": true
```

Kind of a bummer though, I really wanted to disable word suggestions but keep using the JSDoc, but for now I will just filter them out.

Hopefully, this will help someone having this issue.

Comment: The `editor.autoClosingBrackets` suggestion in the other answer did not fix my issue. I too had `"editor.suggest.showWords": false` previously, but changing it to `true` fixed the issue for me even though I *hate* the word suggestions. Guess I'll just add a .vscode folder at the root with project settings for when I'm using JSDoc. This is really annoying.

Comment: No dice for me. Do you _also_ have `autoClosingBrackets` set?

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who has the same problem.

I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82776#issuecomment-544899468) answer useful. It looks like VSCode is treating comments on the same way like Brackets.

`editor.autoClosingBrackets`
I had this configuration on "never" and changed it to "languageDefined".

Answer (score 2):

For me the culprit was the GitHub Copilot extension, like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68346375/3577695).

In summary, disable the extension,

or

open settings (`f1` -> `Open Settings(JSON)`) and add

```json
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
},
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
},
```

and other languages you use I guess

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the `editor.autoIndent` preference setting that was set to `none`. Setting it to `advanced` or `full` fixes the issue with jsdoc indent autocompletion on Enter.

Comment: Mine was on full. Changing it to advanced didn't seem to do anything for me.