# Auto closing brackets in visual-studio-code not working for Vue files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with brackets not auto closing while typing in .vue files. I use visual-studio-code as my editor and i have auto closing brackets set to "always" in settings. HTML tags do self close, and the problem is only in .vue files, while typing in .js/.jsx files everything works normally, brackets and quotation marks auto close. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Vetur extension?

Comment: Same for me after creating vanilla application with vue-cli

Answer (score 32):

For the people that installed `Github copilot extension`!

Know that it does **override settings**! And it's **a cause**!

I never thought about auto closing brackets! It always worked! Till this time it just ceased to do!

You can check this here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739

Even if you are setting

```json
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
```

It will still not work!

> This might be defined by an extension. Are you by any chance using copilot?

You can know why by this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739#issuecomment-874026359):

> Copilot is defining these default language settings that can be overwritten only using language specific settings. They do that to workaround an issue in vscode tracked at [#125663](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125663) . Once we ship our next stable release (sometime this week), they will be free to remove that workaround. Until then you can disable the extension if you are not in the preview program yet or you can define the language specific setting e.g.:

```json
"[typescript]": { "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined" }
```

A guy had it not work for js and typescript! And work out of the box for PHP!

I had **copilot** installed too!

You can just add:

```json
"[typescript]": { "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined" }
"[javascript]": { "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined" }
```

to your settings!

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now it's working again!**

You can also disable **copilot** extension! I didn't want to!

Know too that this copilot issue! Will no more be an issue soon enough! As mentionned in the comment above! You can think about updating it and vscode and check on the next update!

Comment: Yup, github copilot was the reason. Adding these to the settings.json solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, github copilot was the culprit, i just disabled it. Anyways i don't use copilot now..

Comment: Same here, copilot was the culprit

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same issue, even after installing the Vetur extension. **Reloading VS Code solved the problem**.

Comment: This do the tricks on Windows 10, VSCode version 1.56.2

Answer (score 4):

- If you install Vetur plugin in vs-code, reload the application. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue I **solved** the issue by:

Going to settings.json and adding:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
 }
```

*Note: But it does still not work globally, only the language specified.*

*(which is javascript here. You can specify/add any other languages.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by the GitHub Copilot extension. See issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739)
You can fix it by overriding the settings per language file in the VS Code settings.json file.

```
"[javascript]": {
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined",
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```